# Microcontroller with embedded radio and wake on radio

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, radio, wake-on-radio

I am looking for a microcontroller that has radio and WOR (wake on radio) feature all in one...basically a system on chip solution with low power consumption.

I was checking suppliers like TI etc... and couldn't find an all in one solution. TI for example has MSP430 as a nice low power uC, and CC1101 radio chip with WOR function. Too bad that they don't provide this as a single product...but maybe they do and I couldn't find it yet.

I wonder if you know a solution with the features I said....please let me know!

The application I have in mind is quite limited in space, so the smaller the solution, the better!

In particular I am looking for a 433 MHZ radio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about cc430 (msp430 and cc1101 in one)? I used one in 304 and 433 mhz

Answer (score 2):

Have You Checked [Nordic Devices](http://www.nordicsemi.com/)

They offer micro-controller solutions with Ultra Low Power Wireless. Their `ShockBurst` technology is Quite Famous !

Here are two such products.

[8 bit micro based](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24LE1)

[32 bit cortex-m0 based](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRF51-Series-SoC)

Comment: Are you recommending a micro that has an in-built radio i.e. an all in one solution? If you are could you highlight the device please?

Comment: @Andyaka No. Definitely not a micro-controller with inbuilt rf. But a **micro+rf** solution. In past I have searched for exactly this. Will sure put a link to device. My (mobile)internet is running too slow..

Comment: Isn't this what the OP has already located from TI? Are you offering an alternative to what he specifically says he is not looking for?

Comment: The *OP* is asking for a **single product**. *Ti* + *CC1101* are separate. Nordic has the kind he's looking for **unified**. Sorry for confusion !

Comment: OK sounds cool!

Comment: @vvy Would be nice if you can give me the link also. My application has space limit so I hope the one you mean is quite small in size.

Comment: @Sean87 As far I remember the device I'm suggesting is a SOC, it had rf + programmable micro on the same chip, you'd need *antenna*, *crystal* and some external passive components with it though. I'm having trouble opening nordic via my (mobile)internet.

Comment: @vvy no problem I can wait ;)

Comment: Well thanks for keeping the promise alive! Too bad those chips are no 433 MHZ ...actually my bad I had to say that in my post